# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server when trying to condionally render component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm wanting to render my navbar component conditionally based off whether the user is logged in or not but I keep  receiving this error. I'm assuming this has to do with SSR and I'm not sure how to bypass it.

I would love to be able to render my component based off of my state object like I can do with react.js but I can't think of how that's possible if the server pre-renders the page and components.

navbar component

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Context from "../states/AppContext";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../styles/Navbar.module.scss";

const Navbar = () => {
  // const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const value = useContext(Context);
  const user = value.state.auth.user;

  console.log(user);

  if (user) {
    return (
      <nav id={styles.nav}>
        <div id={styles.inner__nav}>
          <Link href="/">
            <a className={styles.logo}>
              <span>Video</span>
              <span>Chattr</span>
            </a>
          </Link>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>Home</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>Login</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>Register</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <nav id={styles.nav}>
        <div id={styles.inner__nav}>
          <Link href="/">
            <a className={styles.logo}>
              <span>Video</span>
              <span>Chattr</span>
            </a>
          </Link>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>Home</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>Logout</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
};

export default Navbar;
```

AppContext.js

```
import React from "react";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

export default AppContext;
```

_app.js

```
import "../styles/Globals.css";
// import "../styles/Index.css";
import "../styles/Forms.scss";
import Layout from "../componenets/Layout";
import { store } from "../app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import AppContext from "../states/AppContext";
import authObject from "../states/auth/authObject";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const authorizationObject = authObject;

  // Context API
  return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={
        {
          state: {
            auth: authorizationObject,
          }
        }
      }>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Will the Authenticating Server-Rendered Pages section help you: https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication

Comment: Can you also show the `/states/auth/authObject` file?